# Why does the PMOS default straight to Triode in this common source amplifier? and how can I mathematically show it?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, analog, common-source

start by assuming both transistors are saturated. even though the title says otherwise
[image]
[image]

I want to find the operating point of this circuit with these parameters.

- Vbiasn = 2V (relative to GND)
- Vbiasp = 3V (relative to GND)
- VDD = 5 V (that circle thing)

---

- (W/L)p=20
- upCox=25uA/V^2
- L=15um
- λp=0.1um/V/L
- VTp=-0.7V

---

- (W/L)n =10
- unCox=50uA/V^2
- L=10um
- λn=0.1um/V/L
- VTn=0.7V

What I did was just equate the square law saturation equations for both NMOS and PMOS and I get a Vx operating point at 2V.
However SPICE tells me that the PMOS is in triode region.
I was reading this website which made sense but I do not know how to mathematically prove what it is saying.
https://cmosedu.com/cmos1/bad_design/bad_design1/bad_design_1.htm

I checked both my equations and with an output operating point at 2V, both MOSFET's could be in saturation.

Can someone tell me why or show me how to prove mathematically that the PMOS will be in triode?

Comment: The bias for the PFET is a negative voltage with respect to the source. Did you consider this?

Comment: @Andyaka edited to show the voltages are relative to GND

Comment: Mathematically, you can calculate the PMOS current and NMOS currents assuming that Vx=2.5V like what you have done. Are both the currents exactly the same? In reality, in simulation, they will not be exactly be the same. There will be a small difference which can shift Vx to a high value pushing PMOS to triode or to a low value pushing the NMOS to triode depending on which current is higher and the magnitude of the RDS of both the transistors

Comment: In your simulation, are you certain your PMOS source is connected to VDD and NMOS source is connected to VSS? I’m also not sure what your version of SPICE does with the 4th terminal when you instantiate a 3-terminal MOSFET. Can you show us the actual simulation?

Comment: @SteKulov https://imgur.com/a/lZwrfCK
Here I made a simulation showing the PMOS going into triode.

Comment: `Vto` should be a negative value for PMOS. Unless you want it to be depletion instead of enhancement.

Comment: That fixed it, for me. Thanks!

Comment: I would add the simulation image to your question and then add an answer which explains the discrepancy.  I can do it for you if you want me to.  Either way.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Discrepancy was that Vto for the PMOS should be -0.7V